# Why is it these two javascript functions seem to not be getting along...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm pretty sure this is n00b question, but I'm completely new to javascript. I'm wondering why this code only prints "hello" but when I comment out the first function, that's when I get the second function to print the other two words. How does this make sense?

```js
var function1 = createFunction();
function createFunction()
{
  console.log("hello");
}
function1(); 

function createFunctionPrinter(word)
{
  console.log(word);
}

var printSample = createFunctionPrinter('sample');
var printNoo = createFunctionPrinter('noo');

printSample(); //should console.log('sample');
printNoo(); //should console.log('noo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function1` is the return value of calling `createFunction` which is `undefined` because `createFunction` has no `return` statement.

`undefined` is not a function, so calling `function1()` raises an exception and execution halts.

Comment: Ohh, okay...but I'm supposed to get it to print to the console. How can I do that and still return something?

Comment: `createFunction` already prints to the console. If you want to return something from it that is not `undefined`, just add a `return` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question. I'm trying to return a function from inside the function that will print to the console. I tried doing something like function createFunction()
{
  return innerfunction(){console.log("hello");}
}
function1(); but it still isn't working..

Comment: That isn't the right syntax for defining a function. You must know the correct syntax for defining a function, you used it twice in the code in the question. Use that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to an method, you should leave the `()`, as the function call return `undefined`.

See this example

```js
function createFunction()
{
  console.log("hello");
}
var function1 = createFunction;
function1(); 

function createFunctionPrinter(word)
{
  console.log(word);
}

var printSample = createFunctionPrinter;
var printNoo = createFunctionPrinter;

printSample('sample'); //should console.log('sample');
printNoo('noo'); //should console.log('noo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing `function1` and `createFunction()` should be easy, provided the fact no arguments are needed for this. Simply set `var function1 = createFunction` without `()` and you it will effectively make `function1` call `createFunction` as if that was the function's name.

`createFunctionPrinter()` is a bit different. My preferred approach is the use of a [prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp), which will take an argument (`word`) when called, and then when you call its `print()` method, it will essentially print your text. The assignment of `printSample` and `printNoo` is similar, but you have to use the `new` keyword. Finally, to make the functions print, use something like `printSample.print()`.

```js
function createFunction() {
  console.log("hello");
}

function createFunctionPrinter(word) {
  this.word = word;
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(word);
  }
}

var function1 = createFunction;
function1();

var printSample = new createFunctionPrinter('sample');
var printNoo = new createFunctionPrinter('noo');

printSample.print();
printNoo.print();
```

**P.S.:** This might not the intended use of prototypes, but I believe it will make your life easier to use them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var function1 = createFunction();

function createFunction()
{
    // return a function that prints a message
    return function() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

function1();
```